# how to find maximum value stored in stack in constant time

Tags: stack, complexity-theory

Using a temp variable to store max value does not work for pop operations.

Comment: You're new here so some advice rather than a close vote: Put some effort into writing your questions. Presumably you're expecting some effort from us, right? So give us more information; show us what you've done so far; be specific about the issues you are having; show us code if you have any. Heck, I put more effort into this comment than you have into your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about O(n) in the push operation:

My personal approach would be to keep a linked list of sorted items.
Whenever you pop an item, compare it to the highest item in the sorted list. If it is the same, remove the highest item from the list, in addition to popping the item. If it is not, just pop the item.

This way, you should always have the highest item at the last element of the linked list, and the time for popping is O(1).

If you also need O(1) for pushing, then I'll have to pass.

Comment: Having a max-Heap instead of a sorted linked list may yield a better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A stack is unsorted, which means that you have to inspect all N values to find the highest. That alone means it is *at least* O(N) while "constant time " means O(1)

Comment: The question doesn't pose constraints on space complexity, so it's doable with additional stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by managing an additional stack that holds maximums.
The algorithm would be like this:
Upon push, compare the new element to the top of the maximums stack. If not less, push it there as well. Upon pop, compare the element to the top of maximums stack. If equal, pop it from there as well.
At any given time, top of maximums stack is the maximum element.